# Redshift sample from table based on count of another table

Tags: sql, select, amazon-redshift, sql-insert, sample

I have TableA of, say, 3000 rows (could be any number < 10000). I need to create TableX with 10000 rows. So I need to select random 10000 - (number of rows in TableA) from TableB (and add in TableA as well) to create TableX. Any ideas please?
Something like this (which obviously wouldnt work):

```
Create table TableX as
select * from TableA
union
select * from TableB limit (10000 - count(*) from TableA);
```

Comment: `select * from tablex limit 10000`?

Comment: TableX doesn't exist. TableB has say millions of rows. I need a random sample from TableB. The amount of that sample is based on the count of rows in TableA. Then combine TableA and random selection from TableB into new table, TableX

Comment: If you don't use an `order by` a `limit` is somewhat random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `union all` and window functions. You did not list the table columns, so I assumed `col1` and `col2`:

```
insert into tableX (col1, col2)
select col1, col2 from table1
union all 
select t2.col1, t2.col2
from (select t2.*, row_number() over(order by random()) from table2 t2) t2
inner join (select count(*) cnt from table1) t1 on t2.rn <= 10000 - t1.cnt
```

The first query in `union all` selects all rows from `table1`. The second query assigns random row numbers to rows in `table2`, and then selects as many rows as needed to reach a total of `10000`.

Actually it might be simpler to select all rows from both tables, then `order by` and `limit` in the outer query:

```
insert into tableX (col1, col2)
select col1, col2
from (
    select col1, col2, 't1' which from table1
    union all 
    select col1, col2, 't2' from table2
) t
order by which, random()
limit 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with inparms as (
  select 10000 as target_rows
), acount as (
  select count(*) as acount, inparms.target_rows 
    from tablea
   cross join inparms
), btag as (
  select b.*, 'tableb' as tabsource, 
         row_number() over (order by random()) as rnum
    from tableb
)
select a.*, 'tablea', row_number() over (order by 1) as rnum
  from tablea
union all
select b.*
  from btag b
  join acount a on b.rnum <= a.target_rows - a.acount
;
```